# This connection is not secure Mozilla

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have deployed an application build in laravel 5.3. On my login forms I see this warning : This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised.

This is my form :

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Login
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                        Forgot Your Password?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</form>
```

What I'm I missing or how can I fix this warning?

Comment: Serve your site over https, not http.

Comment: how can I do this? is is by typing https://www.example.com/ on the browser?

Comment: What does typing URLs in your browser have to do with your web application?

Comment: "Serve your site over https, not http". Kindly explain how this is achieved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Firefox feature](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/20/communicating-the-dangers-of-non-secure-http/) to warn visitors of websites that information they submit is not transferred securely.

The browser shows this warning for pages containing an `<input type="password" />` which are delivered through HTTP instead of HTTPS.

To mitigate this, obtain a certificate for your site and install it, so your users are protected against eavesdropping.